# Entering singapore after being denied entry more than 7 years ago

Tags: visa-refusals

I would need some help in understanding if my wife (who is an Indonesian) can still be granted access to Singapore after being previously denied entry (and was also detained for about 30 days due to usage of 2 passports with different names more than 6 years ago).

if we come to Singapore now, what shall we put in the embarkation card questionnaire that requires input of whether she has been denied entry before ? (shall we tick Yes ?); on the question of using a different passport (shall we also tick Yes ?).

Is there a possibility that re-entering Singapore will risk my wife being detained again based on the background I provided above ?

pls advise.

Respecfully,
Budi

Comment: Being caught, detained (and I assume deported) for having two passports with different names is likely a permanent, big red flag on her record.  I would expect at a minimum lots of secondary questioning when you arrive and the potential for denied entry.

Comment: You should always answer the questions truthfully. If you will tick "yes" it does not mean you will be denied automatically. But if you tick "no" when the true answer was "yes" then you will have a lot of trouble.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/54335/3221

Comment: I would have said the same waht MichaelHampton's comment above links to. There is a chance you will be given entry, but there is a very good chance that you will be caught if you lie.