# ICA Refused entry to Singapore

Tags: customs-and-immigration, singapore, denial-of-entry, polish-citizens

I came to Singapore as a tourist 5th of November. As I am holding a Polish passport I got a visa for 90 days. I left Singapore 4th of February and I went to Bali. I decided to return to Singapore 7th of February. I was going to Singapore with my friend (Singaporean) who declared to pay my accommodation in Singapore for 60 days. I didn't have a return ticket to my country, because I wasn't sure if i will get a visa for 30 or 60 days.

They stopped me at the airport and said that I cannot get in to Singapore. They took pictures of me and fingerprints, but I didn't find any stamp in my passport just paper information with the reason: 'being ineligible for the issue of a pass under current immigration policies'.

My question is: can I come back to Singapore or am I blacklisted? They didn't want to tell me anything at the airport. Where should I try to explain this situation?

Comment: But Can somebody tell me with who should I contact? I mean embassy or ICA? Because they didn't tell me nothing, and what about pixs and fingerprinted? I never had a situation like this before and I am travelling a lot around Asia...

Comment: Check out the link in my above comment: it contains the information you're looking for.

Comment: I think you overstayed by a day as well (Nov: 25 days, Dec/Jan: 62 days, Feb: 4 days. Total: 91 days),

Comment: But can somebody tell me how Can I apply for visa? I have polish passport whats mean I can have 90 days visa, without apply before in embassy. I cannot find info ,

Comment: You apply for the visa at the nearest Singaporean embassy.  However, as described in my answer below, I would *not* recommend you try for another tourist visa.

Comment: Try to keep to one question per post, or it gets lost in the comments. If you have more questions, ask them separately - doesn't matter if you ask lots, its how you and others learn too :D

Comment: Your stay seems to have be 91 or 92 days (not sure how they count it). I guess you have overstayed, did you have to pay a fine when leaving?

Comment: re: contact, general rule is –– if you're in the country, contact an office/ministry (i.e. ICA) and you can also seek legal and procedural advice from embassy of your country, if you're outside the country, contact an embassy/consulate/mission responsible for your current locale. If you are back in Poland, that would probably be in Berlin, email or call to confirm :)

Answer (score 4):

As a citizen of Poland attempting to enter Singapore without a visa, [you are required to have](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PL&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=SG&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) a ticket out of Singapore:

> - Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds to   cover their stay and documents required for their next   destination.
> - **Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused**

Staying in Singapore for the maximum permitted 90 days and returning immediately after a short "visa run" to Bali will also have looked suspicious, since this looks a lot like you're working in Singapore.  Being an Eastern European female, presumably young and unmarried, will also raise suspicion that you're illegally working in the... nightlife industry.

Since your denial is now on the record, [you have likely been blacklisted](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54334/does-being-refused-entry-to-singapore-mean-i-am-now-blacklisted).  Instead of attempting to apply for another tourist visa, I would advise that you apply for a visa that matches the reason you want to stay in Singapore that long: [LTVP](http://www.ica.gov.sg/services_centre_overview.aspx?pageid=376), employment pass, etc.