# I was refused entry to Singapore. Does that mean I am banned or blacklisted?

Tags: visa-refusals, singapore, syrian-citizens

I am of Syrian nationality.  I got a visa to Singapore through the Singapore consulate in Lebanon. I travelled there 28-6-2017. When I reached Singapore, the immigration officer asked me about my return ticket. I showed it to him, but unfortunately I didn't notice that the return date was more than 1 month.  Also he asked for a hotel booking, but I didn't have one. For those reasons, he refused my entry. I was returned back on the same airline.

Is the visa still valid? If I prepare the requested documents and travel again, will I be banned? They didn't stamp my passport. They took a thumb print.

Comment: According to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54334/does-being-refused-entry-to-singapore-mean-i-am-now-blacklisted yes, you are blacklisted.