# Visa rejection, Need sponsorship (Singapore)

Tags: indian-citizens, visa-refusals, singapore, denial-of-entry

My husband has visited Singapore on a tourist visa many times in the last 2-3 years before 2018. The last time he visited was on February 25, 2018, but due to an emergency, he had to come back to India on March 3rd.

He went to Singapore again on March 16th, but at the airport the ICA refused to give him entry. The officers took him to a room and told him to sit there for 2-3 hours. After this time the officers returned and told him he needed a local sponsor whenever he comes back. Without saying anything else or disclosing any other reason they sent him back to India. He did not get any stamp (ban stamp, etc.) on his passport.

A year later he got a local sponsor (his friend) and he applied for his visa on March 16-17, 2019, but it was rejected with some queries by ICA. He fulfilled the requirements asked for by ICA and sent everything by email, but his application was again rejected after one week.

What is the reason behind this? Has he been blacklisted or is there another reason? ICA did not give him any stamp, and they did not disclose any reason for refusing him entry to Singapore. Please advise on how we can deal with this problem.

Comment: Could you add a photograph or transcript of the rejection letters? It's very difficult to help if we don't know the actual reasons for his rejection.

Comment: My guess is that the Singapore authorities believe that after _'so many times'_ visiting on a visitor's visa your husband is not a bona fide visitor. They probably think he's working in Singapore and living there by default. If so, his only option is to stop applying for a while, then apply only sparingly thereafter.

Comment: hi thank you but we don't know the reason. ICA said you need a local sponsor for ur visa now we have a local sponsor but still they are rejecting visa application

Comment: thank you redd herring. but everytime he visited after 3-4 months gap. it means 3-4 times in a year. and total 6-7 times in two years.

Comment: @Eddy malik How long in total has he spent in Singapore during the last year? Has he overstayed on any visit? What was the local sponsor’s relationship to him?

Comment: the last visit was one week 26th feb 2018 to 3rd march 2018.  and about total visits he spent 6-7 months out of two years (August 2016- October 2017).

Comment: No he never ever overstayed in Singapore. he has a good record no complaints etc. and the local sponsor (Singaporean man) is his close friend

Comment: please advise on how we can deal with this problem. we are in trouble

Comment: if you have a legitimate reason to visit Singapore, you will have someone to sponsor you. This does indeed smell mightily like someone trying to illegally work on a tourist visa or someone regularly visiting for other illicit reasons (think criminal transactions). Doesn't have to be the case, but that's what it looks like, and that suspicion is why he gets denied entrance.

Comment: Hi. To help the community suggest the best way forward, can you explain a little more about why your husband visits Singapore regularly? Is this simply as a tourist to see tourist sights, or is this as part of his employment? You say in a recent reply that "we are in trouble" - is there some kind of urgent reason for his visits? If so, explaining the nature of his visits might help other contributors to suggest ways in which he can arrange sponsorship.

Comment: "we are in trouble" I wrote this because we both wanted to go there after marriage and now it is not possible for him.  the second thing is that he visited there once in four-five months for 30 days only to meet his friends. he visits other countries also.

Comment: and he followed all rules and regulations but don't know why it happened

Comment: Your situation doesn't even begin to enter the trouble scale if you just want to go because you feel like it.

Answer (score 4):

If Singaporean Immigration did not explain why they refused him entry or give him the visa refusal reason(s) in writing, and you are certain he has a good travel history and has never breached immigration (or other) laws, there is little we can realistically suggest to help. Your best option is to seek advice from an Immigration lawyer.
Having said that, it does seem unusual that nothing was provided in writing on either occasion. See [Does being refused entry to Singapore mean I am now blacklisted?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54334/does-being-refused-entry-to-singapore-mean-i-am-now-blacklisted)