# Will I guaranteed be blacklisted from entering in Singapore?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, overstaying, singapore

I had overstay in Singapore for 3 days. Is there guaranteed I will be blacklisted from entering Singapore? Or just by chance depending on the period and reason of overstaying?

Comment: Nobody can guarantee anything here because we’re not the officials reviewing your case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does being refused entry to Singapore mean I am now blacklisted?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54334/does-being-refused-entry-to-singapore-mean-i-am-now-blacklisted)