# Am I able to enter Singapore after being denied entry for being in possession of an illegal item?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, singapore, denial-of-entry

I was travelling through Singapore and wanted to stay a few nights to see the place. I came from Amsterdam and had some souvenirs, which I didn't think much of, but when going through customs I was stopped and sent back on the next flight. I was told I had to apply directly to (?) if I wanted to come back again. Any advice please?

Comment: What "souvenirs" did you have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Usually you need to apply for full visa at relevant embassy in country of your resident. This depends on your circumstance though.

Comment: They did not give you death penalty? your souvenir weighted less than 500 grams then!

Comment: @JonathanReez from Amsterdam? Cheese, obviously.

Comment: @DonQuiKong There are no restrictions on bringing personal use quantities of cheese into Singapore: https://www.sfa.gov.sg/food-import-export/bringing-food-for-personal-use

Comment: @lambshaanxy: I believe you missed the attempt at humor...

Comment: @dda Maybe OP was trying to import some humor, because that's *definitely* illegal in Singapore.

Comment: @JonathanReez The OP came out of Amsterdam and you really have to ask what souvenirs?

Comment: If it was drugs, OP wouldn't have been turned back, it would be prison, caning or wirse,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the words, 'Amsterdam', 'Souvenir', I assume you got deported as you had some drugs or things associated with drugs.

Singapore takes drug-related offenses pretty seriously. So, it's more than likely that you might be permanently banned, or at least your passport is flagged.

So, I suggest to proceed with extreme caution if you are trying again.

Comment: Amsterdam had more than weed, it is kind of insulting to make it an automatic connection.

Comment: Can you give me an instance which can result in such a deportation?

Comment: @Willeke True, Amsterdam has loads of stuff to offer, but not much else would cause problems in SG.

Comment: It is insulting to assume that a visit to Amsterdam and a deportation are related without having more details. Many cities have more drugs use than Amsterdam but this kind of reactions make it very hard to get rid of the reputation.

Comment: What I can think of is he may be caught with something that can be used for Drugs, but not actual drugs. Eg- Bong, canabis roller or something like that.

Other thing I can think of is e-cigarettes. But it doesn't warrant a deportation.

Comment: @Willeke OP stated that their souvenir from Amsterdam was an "illegal item" in Singapore. If it's not drug paraphernalia, then what else could it be? A biohazardous herring?

Comment: Amsterdam has also Heineken beer, and if someone is punished for trying to bring even infinitesimal quantities somewhere else than the toilet drain I would be happy.
Given that Singapore has death penalty for drug smugglers and that the Amsterdam is the city visited by 90% of its tourists because of some stupid repressive laws in their own countries, it is reasonable to expect that ...

Comment: Obviously the guy brought some radioactive tulips into Singapore! @Willeke What else from Amsterdam would get the guy deported? Unless the guy brought a legal prostitute into Singarpore in a suitcase.

Comment: @stackoverblown Oddly, prostitution *is* legal in Singapore. It's tightly regulated though, you can't just BYO.

Answer (score 12):

Being denied entry into Singapore is [usually accompanied by being blacklisted](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54334/does-being-refused-entry-to-singapore-mean-i-am-now-blacklisted) for a period of at least 6 months.  Anecdotally, blacklists over 1 year are reserved for serious offenses; if you got out with no fines or jail time, your offense was likely not "serious".

I would advise waiting out *at least* a year and then applying for a visa at an embassy in advance, instead of just showing up and taking your chances.  (This is almost certainly what they meant by "applying directly to" somewhere.). And prepare yourself for the possibility that the visa will still be denied.

Comment: Let's make it clear that there is no guarantee whatsoever that a visa will be granted after this incident, even after the ban officially expires: it is now part of OP's history and every application will yield this incident, which is likely to result in enough "negative points" to deny the visa. The longer OP waits before re-applying the better.

Comment: @jcaron My understanding is that blacklists over one year are reserved for serious offenses (working illegally etc), getting turned back at the border with no further consequences is unlikely to qualify.  But yeah, there's a very real chance visa applications will be denied for a while.

Comment: Unless OP really has to go to Singapore, I would advise against this. If, as seems quite likely, the application is denied then for the rest of his life he will have to say “yes” when he’s applying for a visa and he’s asked if he’s ever had a visa application denied.

Comment: @MikeScott To further stress that: Being denied a visa for whatever reasons/whatever country is usually considered a red flag for ANY OTHER country you are trying to get a visa for.

Comment: @MikeScott Usually, the forms that ask about visa refusals also ask about deportations and other adverse immigration decisions, and deportations and refusal of entries are usually seen as more serious than visa refusals alone. That said, it is better to avoid piling on refusal records.

Comment: @xngtng He might not technically have been denied entry to Singapore — they may have given him the option to voluntarily withdraw his application to enter.